# How to change picture orientation in Xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode, image, landscape

I get a picture from the photo library and call it image using this code:

```
@IBAction func importImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(image, animated: true) { }
}
```

and this code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        myImageView.image = image
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        SubmitBtnOutlet.isHidden = false;
        Gurpcontroller.person = "yours";
        Gurpcontroller.collecterthing = "Coin";
        PictureViewController.imageuniversal = myImageView
    } else {
        //Error message
    }
}
```

I want to see if image is landscape or portrait. Then, if it is landscape I want to change it to portrait.

Comment: By definition, *landscape* means the image **size** is more width than height. So if an image is 200 width by 100 height, could you include more details on what you want? If your UIImageView is 200 by 200, you can always use *.scaleAspectFit*, but it's difficult to know if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Polished code syntax a bit to be as concise as possible and remove empty space. Also changed title wording slightly (orientate is not a word, but is represented by the phrase "change orientation" the way I understood the author). I also fixed minor spelling of `portrait`, to clarify the question as an image orientation question to always get the image to `portrait` mode.

Comment: In terms of the answer, the first comment by @dfd is spot on -- if an image's width is larger than it's height, it is by definition in `landscape` mode. From there, you can rotate or crop to your heart's content to recover a `portrait` image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the orientation by using `image.imageOrientation`.

In order to change the orientation, the quickest solution would be to create a new UIImage from the actual image as follows:

```
let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: .up)
```

Comment: It wont let me do it this is what i put                                                                              var newImage = PictureViewController.imageuniversal.image
                                                                                                         
       newImage = UIImage(cgnewImage: newImage?.cgImage!, scale: newImage?.scale, orientation: .up)

Comment: Please read the answer properly. The variable `image` is the image you want to manipulate. The variable `newImage` is the one which will store the resulting image. `cgImage` is the parameter name, you cannot change it to `cgnewImage`. Also you are using `newImage`'s properties on the right hand side. Basically you are trying to access the properties of an image that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Use these lines of code instead 
`let image = PictureViewController.imageuniversal.image`
`let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: .up)`